# how to open program through C# program and give this program focus

Tags: c#, .net, focus

How to open program through C# program (Windows Mobile) and give this program focus ?

**EDIT by MarkJ**: Gold says thanks for Process.Start suggestions, but for some reason the program still doesn't get the focus.

Thanks in advance,
Gold

Comment: By "give this program focus" do you mean your program or the program you just launched?

Comment: Have you set the TopMost property of the Form in the original application to true? If so, the program you start will not be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch a program by calling [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), like this:

```
Process.Start(programPath);
```

You can also pass in a file (eg, a Word document), or even a web site, and it will automatically launch in the default program for that file type on the user's machine.

When you call `Process.Start`, the program should automatically receive focus.

Comment: Gold says the program starts, but doesn't get the focus. (In another question, that's now been closed as a duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Process.Start();` to start your process and then:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public static bool BringWindowToTop(string windowName, bool wait)
{
      int hWnd = FindWindow(windowName, wait);
      if (hWnd != 0)
      {
           return SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)hWnd);
      }
      return false;
}
```

To find window and bring it to front

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start()`??

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below should automatically put the window on top.

```
Process.Start("path");
```